# Pass value to controller after dropping item .net core mvc

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, jquery-ui

I was wondering what's the best approach:
I have a grid with images of cities. The user can drop an image of a citie in a "departure" field and the same for the arrival. after that,  the user needs to select the departure date.

The drag and drop is done with Jquery UI. But how can you add the values of the departure and the arrival to the form  and pass it to the controller using .net core mvc. Is there a way to populate a dropdown when the image is dropped and set the asp-for on the dropdown or to set the value in the model before passing it to the controller?

I'm new with .net core and it's hard to know which is the best approach.

Comment: Here you come after you tried and tried again and again different solution and the code that you tried didn't work. So you put that code here and the questions. Beside that you can search online what are you looking for.

Comment: From your description, I think you need to use javascript to achieve it, Please provide a minimal executable demo for use to test.